# Asp.Net authentication with VS2013 and Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, visual-studio-2013

I use Login.aspx authentication page in a VS2010/4.0 project with success for few years.
After migrating a copy of this project to VS2013/4.5, I can't log in.
However I can successfully create new accounts with Register.aspx What makes me say that connection to remote database works.
I don't know what's wrong. Something with cookies ?

Here is my Web.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <!-- Ajouté par moi depuis le app.config le 20/12/2013 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AspNetEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AspNetModel.csdl|res://*/AspNetModel.ssdl|res://*/AspNetModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MaBaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MaBaseModel.csdl|res://*/MaBaseModel.ssdl|res://*/MaBaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MaBaseEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Turf2012Model.csdl|res://*/Turf2012Model.ssdl|res://*/Turf2012Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices2" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MaBaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="GE2011EntitiesSav" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Ge2011.csdl|res://*/Ge2011.ssdl|res://*/Ge2011.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=GE2011;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="GE2011Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Ge2011.csdl|res://*/Ge2011.ssdl|res://*/Ge2011.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Ge2014Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Ge2014Model.csdl|res://*/Ge2014Model.ssdl|res://*/Ge2014Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSERVER.com,1086;initial catalog=MaBase;user id=ZZZZZZZZZZ;password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ADMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ADMModel.csdl|res://*/ADMModel.ssdl|res://*/ADMModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MYSERVER.com,1086;Initial Catalog=MaBase;User ID=ZZZZZZZZZZ;Password=XXXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <location path="google1a68c74470992d81.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="WebForms/MaPageXXX.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="WebForms/MaPageXXX.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Turf Administrateur" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="WebForms/MaPageXXX.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="ADM Administrateur" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="WebForms/MaPageXXX.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Webmasters" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <!--
    Pour obtenir une description des modifications de web.config, voir http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    Les attributs suivants peuvent être définis dans la balise <httpRuntime>.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/WebForms/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
    </authentication>
    -->
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="Proxy Handler" path="Proxy.ashx" verb="*" type="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.Proxy, DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com" />
      <add name="Image Handler" path="ImageHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.WebForms.ImageHandler, DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseEntities">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseEntitiesAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseEntities" />
      </service>
      <service name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.Ge2014">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.Ge2014AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.Ge2014" />
      </service>
      <service name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBase">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBase" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseEntitiesAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.Ge2014AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="DBM.ZZZZZZZZZZ.com.MaBaseAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
      <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
           before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
           be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
      <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <runtime>
    <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
    <!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
         to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
     -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.15.0" newVersion="2.2.15.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
          <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
            <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
          </trustedProviders>-->
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
               with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
      <provider />
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Here is part of site.master page:

```
                        <div class="loginDisplay">
                            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                                <AnonymousTemplate>
                                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Se connecter</a> ]
                                </AnonymousTemplate>
                                <LoggedInTemplate>
                                    Bienvenue <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Se déconnecter" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                                </LoggedInTemplate>
                            </asp:LoginView>
                            <asp:Image ID="m_IconeAdministrateur" runat="server"  class="IconeAdministrateur" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icone_Administrateur01.png"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Check your cookies with fiddler, to see if it gives you a cookie. I struggled with the same, also could you post your Web.config?

Comment: Thanks, Here is my Web.Config:

Comment: Thanks, I can't send web.config because is too long. brleclerc@free.fr

Comment: Edit your original question, and embed the Web.Config inside a code-tag with the editor. Like this : http://i.imgur.com/0YkHIdh.png

Comment: Web.Config is now in original Question. Thanks.

Comment: When you mention that the login page no longer works, what do you mean by that?  For instance, is the server giving you an "invalid username or password" error?  Is it attempting to set a cookie (as seen by a Fiddler trace) and redirecting, but the cookie is not being accepted after the redirect?  If you attach a debugger and enable first chance exceptions, are any exceptions thrown during or immediately after login?

Comment: If I set wrong login, server returns "invalid username / password". If I set goog login, nothing appends, login page is only refreshed, no loggin message display with welcome message. I can also create new account, I can see it in the remote database. Yes I can see send and recieve cookies with firebug but I'm not able to analyse them. There is no First Chance exception. Thanks.

Comment: I saw authentication section is commented out in your web.config. What is the authentication mode you used? Can you please share more details on your authentication method? Can you use fiddler and see what is the response code you get after you enter correct login? 302->200? Thanks!

Comment: I Just add part of site.Master page (authentication form).

Comment: This have been working fine for a few years, but I probably made a change recently which could cause this behavior. Thanks. Sorry I have neither recent backup no change management :-(

Comment: Juster after entering Username and Password, with FireBug, I can see 302 error on the first post to /account/login.aspx and just after a 200 on get /account/login.aspx. I don't understand

Comment: You are right  X-Mao ! I do not know for what kind of reason this text is commented. Now all works fine. thanks to all.